# volttron log file management best practices

Tags: volttron

Is there a way to limit the size of the `volttron.log` file? At the moment I can see that is a couple gigs in size and it makes `less` crash when trying to find something to troubleshoot.

Is it possible to use like a CRON service or something that could run just to keep like 2 days worth of data? I dont think I would need any more than that. Or does volttron have anything out of the box for file management?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When starting volttron you can set up a rotating log file.

In the "./start-volttron" script (https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron/blob/main/start-volttron) there is a command that uses a log definition file.

```
volttron -L examples/rotatinglog.py > volttron.log 2>&1 &
```

By default this examples/rotatinglog.py file has a weekly log retention and changes the log each 24hr period.

Comment: To use rotating log files, should I be doing a `./start-volttron --rotating` I think this is the proper way to implement and NOT the answer in the post?

Comment: They both do the same thing actually.  Just make sure that there isn't a volttron instance on the current $VOLTTRON_HOME before executing it.